# the server exited prematurely with exit code 1 on glassfish 4.0

Tags: glassfish

when I tried to start glassfish domain using

```
asadmin start-domain domain1
```

getting an error saying

> the server exited prematurely with exit code 1 on glassfish 4.0 before it died it produced the following output

full stack trace is

```
the server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:
Java Hotspot(TM) 64 bit server vm warning: ignoring options MaxPermsize=192m, supported was removed in 80
ERROR: JDWP option syntax error: -agentlib: jdwp=transport=dt_Socket,Server=y,Suspend=n,address=9009
command start-domain failed
```

can anyone help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

you have to change network listener   port number in **glassfish\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml** after that it will work fine.

Comment: Dude, you're a legend. I was stuck on a problem in a different situation and this helped. So, for anyone else who may have my problem: I was trying to run an arquillian test in a glassfish managed container on a Jenkins CI server. The gf server wouldn't start during the test and somehow I got here and this fixed me up nice and proper. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo asadmin start-domain
```

worked perfect for me.

Comment: This worked for me. But I am curious why? `./asadmin start-domain domain1` worked perfectly fine for me before.

Comment: Or you can add `..\glassfish\bin` to your envirmentpath. then write `asadmin` in the terminal, press enter and write then `start-domain domain1`

Answer (score -3):

I faced a similar problem, in my case it was happening due to Java. Check the version in **asenv.bat** file of **glassFish**.