# Could not find or load main class Files.Microsoft while starting GlassFish 4.0

Tags: glassfish-4

I am trying to start glassfish, but all the time get this error

```
PS C:\glassfish4\bin> ./asadmin start-domain mydomain
Waiting for mydomain to start .Error starting domain mydomain.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

Error: Could not find or load main class Files.Microsoft
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0

Command start-domain failed.
```

Maybe you have any ideas how to solve this issue? I have found nothing about such an error in the internet.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721686/the-server-exited-prematurely-with-exit-code-1-on-glassfish-4-0
Check this link, it may be helpful for your problem.

Comment: no, this is not a duplicate